# Phpstorm 8 vs PHP 5.1.6 & CentOS 5.5

Tags: php, phpstorm, remote-debugging

Is it possible to configure remote debugging with PHP version 5.1.6? The development server imitates some old production environment (CentOS 5.5 + PHP 5.1.6). It seems that Phpstorm supports only PHP versions beginning with 5.3... For 5.1.6 it says 'PHP version: Not installed' (the connection via SFTP is OK since I can explicitly choose the /usr/bin/php file and also to get from and deploy to server all of the project files):
[image]

Posted this question to JetBrains yesterday, still no answer.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No clue -- never worked with 5.1. But I know that 5.2. can definitely be recognized by PhpStorm. What you need to check first it's if that PHP installation produces any warnings (start up errors) -- [IDE is quite sensitive to them, at least in the past](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-15976). Just run something like `php -v` via SSH and check the output. Please also note that in PhpStorm v8 you have to [point to actual executable](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-13110) and not just folder (as in previous versions)

Comment: /usr/bin/php is the actual executable. All that gives me `php -v` is: `PHP 5.1.6 (cli) (built: Mar 18 2014 20:48:55) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2006 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2006 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans`. But I've already received an answer from JetBrains support: `We don't support debugging with 5.1 version unfortunately. Supported versions start from 5.3, that's correct.` Sigh.